Error creating Bootable USB stick
I tried to create a bootable USB stick for ubuntu 24.04 using balenaEtcher and I keep getting the following error message "Something went wrong. If it is a compressed image, please check that the archive is not corrupted". Same error when I used ubuntu 22 instead. Thanks for the help.

Did you verify checksums of the image (google how to) ? Maybe the ISO image got corrupted.

sadly I frequently find USB memory sticks are bad ... try using a different one

Are you running balenaEtcher in Ubuntu or in Windows? If in Windows, please try Rufus. If in Ubuntu, please try the Startup Disk Creator alias usb-creator-gtk or mkusb. - If you suspect problems caused by the hardware of the USB stick, you can analyze the problem according to this link and if you are lucky, find a solution.

If you suspect problems caused by BalenaEtcher, please try another tool (as suggested in the previous comment). If you suspect problems caused by the Ubuntu iso file, please check it with sha256sum.

If you are installing a Ubuntu boot disk from Ubuntu, you can use the application "Startup Disk Creator", which comes with Ubuntu by default.

Thank you all for the responses. I tried Sudolus' recommendation of using Rufus and it worked instantly.

I'd reformat the usb stick with 'erase' option in Disks, just to make sure that there is no corruption of the stick (assuming there is enough useable room on the stick)
Then download the latest balenaEtcher Appimage & redownload the ISO as well.
As mention by a previous respondent, iso's can be corrupted.

To create bootable flash drives, I recommend using Ventoy, it is much simpler and more convenient.
You only need to install the application itself on the flash drive, then simply copy the necessary ISO to the drive and select it when booting.
